# APACHE + PHP Http request fails at 30 s even after increasing max_execution_time

Tags: php, apache, http, timeout

I noticed that my HTTP requests are failing almost exactly at 30 s. Naturally I thought that there is a configuration for the timeout. Hence I updated the

```
max_execution_time 300
max_input_time 600
```

And still the problem persists.

I have a simple script to test it as well.

```
<?php
  echo "starting ...";
  sleep(40);
  echo "end ...";
```

The request fails at 30s. Although if I reduce the sleep to 25, everything works fine.

ps. 
I noticed that the browser sometimes reissues / resubmits the request after 30s. Therefore, I am leaning towards this being a webserver (Apache2) issue ?

phpinfo() displays the updated values

Any thoughts ?

Comment: check if you got configured timeout in httpd.conf http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout

Comment: Timeout= 3000. Mentioned in apache2.conf. Is there a way, I can see/know which was the timeout that was actually applied ?

Answer (score 2):

Restart the apache!

[              ]

Comment: Tried that and even restarted the server itself. Neither worked !